# SSH port-forwarding works on one port but not on the other

Tags: ssh, portforwarding

I am trying this command

```
ssh username@example -L 27017:10.230.0.6:27017 -L 9201:10.290.0.8:9200 -L 5601:10.210.0.5:5601
```

The port forwarding works for the 27107 but not the others, do I need to override the ports?

I always get the same error which is:

```
channel 8: open failed: connect failed: Connection timed out
```

channel 7: open failed: connect failed: Connection timed out

Answer (score 1):

```
ssh username@example ... -L 9201:10.290.0.8:9200 -L 5601:10.210.0.5:5601
...
channel 8: open failed: connect failed: Connection timed out
```

When you connect to port 9201 or 5601 on your local system, that connection is tunneled through your ssh link to the ssh server on the remote ssh server. From there, the ssh server makes a TCP connection to the target of the tunnel--10.290.0.8:9200 or 10.210.0.5:5601--and relays data between the tunneled connection and the connection to target of the tunnel.

The "Connection timed out" error is coming from the remote ssh server when it tries to make the TCP connection to the target of the tunnel. "Connection timed out" means that the ssh server process transmitted a TCP connection request to the target system, and it never received a response.

Common reasons for a connection timeout include:

1. The target system is down or disconnected from the network.
2. Some firewall or other network device is blocking traffic between the ssh server and the target system.
3. The IP address and/or port is incorrect, and the connection attempts are going to the wrong place.